# Is my Anchor Hocking Oven Basics glass measuring cup inaccurate?

Tags: cookware

[image]

For measuring I usually use my red plastic Betty Crocker cups.
While rearranging some dishes, I noticed the 1 cup line on the 2 cup Anchor H one looked off - greater than one cup. I poured one cup from the plastic one into the 2cup Anchor Hocking one and there was a discrepancy. See photo. Also true of the glass 1 cup AH one.
This seems enough to make a difference in some recipes and general measuring. I appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Agree you should weight it. But... American Cup vs Metric cup?

Comment: There's no such thing as a metric 'cup', it only applies to US measures. It was never even a valid measure when the UK used Imperial. As a non-American I always thought it the most confusing measure... It's half a pint, but as a US pint isn't even the same as an Imperial pint, it's half of something I can't even measure anyway ;-) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pint

Comment: !@#$%^&* Now you have me checking all my measuring cups! :-)

Comment: All of my mom's Pyrex cups are off. They expect that you learned probably nothing in chemistry class and measure from the top of the miniscus. Which means that if you measure properly (from the bottom of the miniscus, like you learned in school), you will routinely overmeasure! It's extremely frustrating.

Comment: This looks a good 1/8 cup too little though, more than the miniscus error!

Comment: Counter doesn't look to be level.

Comment: I've always wondered how well they register (align) the printing on the side of measuring cups ... I've seen a few in discount stores that were obviously off.

Comment: @MaxW and I will use water and a scale >.<

Answer (score 4):

I'd get a third measuring tool to see which one is wrong.

One way to test this is to measure by weight (and IMO, all recipes should list ingredients by weight instead of volume)

1 cup of water is about 236ml which is 236g.

Get 1 cup from your red cup and weight it.
Get 1 cup from your glass cup and weight it.

It should tell you which one is right.

And to answer your question, yes, for some recipes, if you add too much or too liltle liquid it will not result in different results (either too dry or too wet).

Comment: Thank you @ Max. Will do! It's just puzzling as these cups are from two major brands.

Comment: 2 out of 3 of my most used measuring cups have the scale printed at an angle... that's how much care & attention they take with these things ;) I'm with Max on anything needing critical amounts - I use my scales, which will amongst other things do fl oz/ml & tare. Problem solved.

Comment: @Tetsujin It sounds like your measuring cups are the kind designed to separate oil from broth... (maybe?)

Comment: @elbrant - No, they're simply carelessly made, the prints are askew... by a mile. I'm assuming by the [Moscow Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moscow_rules) that it's merely coincidence... I really don't suspect 'enemy action'  ;)

Answer (score -1):

Pyrex glass measuring cups are for liquids.
Plastic and metal "cups" are for dry ingredients.

It's an old rule of thumb that no one seems to remember...

---

The issue is a difference in volume.

One half gallon of milk weighs 4#s, contains 8 cups (8x8oz = 64oz/8 = 4#s).
Four pounds (#s) of sugar also contains 64oz. 
Weights can be equal, but the mass (or volume) of objects can be different. A pound of feathers still weighs a pound, but it takes more space to hold them (than it does to hold a pound of sugar).

Comment: And what does that mean considering volumetric measurements? Shouldn’t a cup be a cup?

Comment: ["The measurement of weight and volume are 2 different things."](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/mathematics-statistics/difference-between-fluid-ounces-and-ounces/)

Comment: But that’s for **ounces**, where there’s indeed a **liquid** and **dry** ounce - the former a volumetric, the latter a weight unit that happen to share a name. I have never heard of a “solid cup” or other *weight-based* cup? Of course a cup of flour weights less than a cup of water, but a cup should always have the same volume (regional differences like a US tablespoon being different from a AUS tablespoon, for example, may apply).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "weight-based" cup. A cup of anything refers to 8oz - wet or dry. The amount of space it takes to contain the item would refer to it's "mass" or "volume". A pound of feathers still equals 16oz. -- it's just going to require a much larger container to hold it.

Comment: A cup of anything refers to 8 oz - meaning the *liquid* measure, even if you measure a dry substance. For the dry ounce, you need a scale. That you can use either a scale or a container works just for water (due to the specific volumetric density) or liquids comparable to it, exactly because a cup of feathers *weighs* way less than a cup of water, for example.

Comment: Not neccessarily. Weight is interchangeable. 1/8C = 1 fluid oz = 2T = 6tsp = 30ml  Volume is not.

Comment: Erm, but that’s all volumes in this list?

Comment: Can someone go knock on the White House door & tell them it's time they caught up with the rest of the world... "one open, one shut, span of my hand & half a brick + my thumb on the scale == half a hogshead" is really not the way to measure things any more.. One dry cup != one wet cup.... I despair ;-)

Comment: @Stephie Correct, we can assume a "Cup" of Feathers would refer to the volume, not the weight. Which is the point. Not everything that weighs 8oz will fit into a standard 1C measuring device, neither fluid or dry, because of it's volume/mass.

If 16oz = 1#, then 1/8C (1 fluid oz) = 1/16# in weight. Not Volume.  (You seem to have weight and volume flipped.)

Comment: Sorry, but please re-read your answer (which triggered this discussion): your first sentence implies that there are two different units for *cups* (that’s what the asker is talking about) - which I think is wrong.

Comment: It's not wrong. [Perhaps this article will help you understand the concept better.](https://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-between-ounces-and-fluid-ounces-224303)

Comment: As I understand it, one (American) cup is a volumetric measurement equal to 236.6 ml, which is equal to 8 **fl oz** (a measurement of volume). 8 fl oz of water actually weighs 236.6 g, which is 8.35 oz. So one (American) cup of water does not actually weigh 8 oz.

Comment: @elbrant - As a chemist I'm not accepting your argument. "Measuring cups" are for measuring volume, not mass. Yes there is some old correlation to ounces of water and fluid volume but that is long out of use. If you try to measure mass by measuring volume you need a unique cup for everything you're measuring. The "measuring cup" for water won't work for oil. Also sugar is available in a number of different particle sizes. So you'd need one cup for table (granulated) sugar and another for confectioner's sugar. So using volume to measure mass is just useless in the kitchen.

Comment: @MaxW Consider the word "mass" erased. The issue is between weight and volume. Most oil is considered a fluid and would be measured using a Pyrex measuring cup. Sugar (a dry good) would be measured in a basic measuring cup. I was using mass and volume interchangably -- my bad, I'm ashamed. Happy?

Comment: @elbrant Measuring cups are for measuring volume, not weight OR mass.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because, in the US, this is exactly how measuring cups are sold and meant to be used for (American) recipes. The liquid measuring cups are for liquids and measure fluid ounces.  Dry measuring cups are for measuring dry ingredients, and roughly standardize amounts of different ingredients. E.g. 1 cup of flour, 1 cup of sugar, etc. While I agree that using scales to weigh ingredients is much more precise, it doesn't make this answer wrong.

Comment: Interestingly enough, out of sheer curiosity, I took two 1 cup dry measuring cups (two different 'no name' brands), filled each with water and then poured each into a Pyrex liquid measuring cup. In each case, the amounts matched exactly. So, in this case, 1 cup = 1 cup!